# InfluxDB With GoLang

Tags: database, go, influxdb

I'm very new to InfluxDB and seem to be having some trouble understanding how to use the Go client. I'm currently using the default example code but I can't understand where to find the data that is being uploaded, or if it is being uploaded at all. The current code looks like

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    influxdb2 "github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-go/v2"
)

func main() {

    token := "tokenInsertedHere"

    fmt.Println("testing influxdb")
    // Create a new client using an InfluxDB server base URL and an authentication token
    client := influxdb2.NewClient("http://localhost:8086", token)
    // Use blocking write client for writes to desired bucket
    writeAPI := client.WriteAPIBlocking("orgName", "bucketName")
    // Create point using full params constructor
    p := influxdb2.NewPoint("test",
        map[string]string{"unit": "temperature"},
        map[string]interface{}{"avg": 24.5, "max": 45.0},
        time.Now())
    // write point immediately
    writeAPI.WritePoint(context.Background(), p)
    client.Close()
}
```

When I'm on the data explorer page filtering measurements in the bucket the code should've wrote to, the measurement doesn't pop up. What am I doing wrong? I've noticed that the client doesn't throw any errors, which is strange to me. I've tried using a fake token and it acts like there were no problems when writing to the db. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

I can't conclusively know if this is your issue, but keeping my token and org names lined up correctly always trips me up. In the Influx web client, go to "Switch Organizations" and verify that the organization that you are using matches the organization selected in the web client. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line with write to catch an error and check what error occured:

```golang
   err := writeAPI.WritePoint(context.Background(), p)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
```

Comment: thank you! i probably should've read the docs more, but didn't realize until now that the function returned an error

Comment: A good IDE should show an unhandled error (Goland does).
Have figured out what is wrong?

Comment: yeah i'm super surprised that vscode didn't show that to me. i haven't gotten back to it yet since i'm working on a few other things right now, but i should be getting back to it soon i hope